# Poetry creates a project with wrong Python version

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyenv

I am attempting to create a poetry project with the latest version of Python install via my pyenv installation with homebrew.  The below terminal commands show the versions of pyenv and poetry that I have.

```
path/user % pyenv --version
pyenv 2.3.9
path/user % pyenv versions
  system
* 3.9.6 (set by /Users/user/.pyenv/version)
path/user % poetry --version
Poetry (version 1.3.1)
path/user % poetry new venv
Created package venv in venv
path/user % ls
venv
path/user % cd venv
(base) user@user venv % ls
README.md   pyproject.toml  tests       venv
```

Resulting `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "venv"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["user <email@email.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

```
(base) user@user venv % poetry env use 3.9.6
The specified Python version (3.9.6) is not supported by the project (^3.11).
Please choose a compatible version or loosen the python constraint specified in the pyproject.toml file.
```

The issue I am having is that, despite only having Python version 3.9.6 installed on my machine, the poetry project is being created with a default of Python version 3.11 each time.  What am I doing wrong and how do I solve the issue?

I attempted uninstalling and reinstalling both pyenv and poetry via homebrew.  Before creating the poetry project, I also tried `pyenv local 3.9.6`, but this didn't work, either.

Goal: Be able to create a poetry project `poetry new venv` without having to manually update the pyproject.toml file each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Poetry initializes new projects and creates new venvs with the Python version that was used for installing Poetry itself.

This is why you have `python = "^3.11"` in your `pyproject.toml`.

> The specified Python version (3.9.6) is not supported by the project (^3.11).

This method tells you, that your project aimed to be compatible for python >=3.11,<4.0, but you are trying to use a `python3.9` interpreter. You have to manual edit the `pyproject.toml` and set `python = "^3.11"` to whatever fits your needs.

To enable Poetry to pick up the currently activated version of Python, you have to set the config option `virtualenvs.prefer-active-python` to `true`. See https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsprefer-active-python-experimental

Please note that at the moment this option is not respected on `poetry new` or `poetry init`. Until https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/7100 is merged and released you still have to edit the `pyproject.toml` by hand.

Comment: So the python version in the pyproject.toml reads as though it is greater or equal to the version of 3.11?

If I change this to, say, 3.0.1, I could use any version of 3.0.1 and greater? @finswimmer

Comment: The `^` is described here: https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#caret-requirements

Comment: I've looked, and it still don't understand.  I am stupid @finswimmer

Comment: @ahhhgetit, no, it's not you. The caret requirements specification is confusing and awkward: "An update is allowed if the new version number does not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the major, minor, patch grouping." You really have to look closely at the examples to understand the implications. I think it's counterintuitive.